# Can we build Gluon Mobile for Android (APK) from Windows without installing Linux?

Tags: javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile

From [gluon documentation](https://docs.gluonhq.com/#platforms_android_development) it say that

```
Currently, Android can be built only on Linux OS (or from Windows WSL2).
```

but if I run this [gluon sample](https://github.com/gluonhq/hello-world/) that use gradle, I can run this sample on my android device and able to build the APK.

The problem when I build the project from scrath using gluon plugin that integrated with IDE, I'm not able to run the sample on my device without changing any generated code. I already try gradle or maven as build tool.

Comment: The doc also says "Alternatively you can use a GitHub Actions workflow.", see https://github.com/gluonhq/hello-gluon-ci. The sample you are linking uses the old `jfxmobile` plugin for Java 8. For Java/JavaFX 11+ the Client plugin uses GraalVM and Android can only be targeted from a Linux OS.

Comment: If you have errors building a project, post them, so we can help. Make sure you use the latest IDE plugin.

Comment: @JoséPereda thank for the reply, I will try github action instead. So this mean, if I use Java 11 and I already install GraalVM on my Windows computer I still can't build Android APK?

Comment: If you want to build for Android on your Windows machine you have to install Linux via WSL2, that works quite fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, it's not possible to build an Android package (APK) from Windows. But we can use WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) and run all the commands from the Linux command. You can get WSL from
[Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu-2004-lts/9n6svws3rx71?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) and it's really easy to install. So we can code and run on Windows to see the output of the app and use Linux ONLY when we want to deploy on Android.